# How to dismiss material dialog(afollestad) from the adapter it is calling?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

how to call `materialDialog.dismiss()` inside the `DialogAdapter(mContext,nListId,(ArrayList<String>)imagelist)` , so that dialog is dismissed through the Adapter?
i have tried passing `materialDialog` as a parameter to the `Dialogadapter` , but calling `materialDialog.dismiss()` in `OnBindViewHolder()` gives null pointer Exception.
This is the link to the Material Dialog library : https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

```
materialDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(mContext)
                                    .title("Choose Node")
                                    .adapter(new DialogAdapter(mContext,nListId,(ArrayList<String>)imagelist,materialDialog), null)
                                    .positiveText("YES")
                                    .negativeText("CANCEL")
                                    .build();
                                    .show();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Listener for that purpose